# Bulk Insert with extra column

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, bulk

Hi
I have a csv file (coming from excel), and I use BULK INSERT to insert it into my table. The number of columns in the table match the number of columns in csv file.

But I need an extra column in my table that can be called for example Processed. Ideally this would be a bit column and initially all the values would be false.

Is there a (easy) way to accomplish this

Thanks

--MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [sql bulk insert with additional column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915209/sql-bulk-insert-with-additional-column) suggests I ended up creating a view, bulk inserting into view, and using table (with extra column). Works well and is easy. Perhaps another option is format table, but I have not investigated this enough.