# How to import CSV to SQL and insert file name to the last column?

Tags: sql, import, sql-server-2008-r2

I have many CSV files and I want to import them to MyTable using BULK INSERT. Each time I import a new file I want to insert to last column 'ColumnNameWithFileName' the name of the file. The files are named like file01.csv, file02.csv etc.

When I try to use BULK INSERT while importing second file I get truncation error. Probably because the CSV table does not fit MyTable where already is additional column. How to handle this?

`-- Add a column 'ColumnNameWithFileName' This code done only once
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD ColumnNameWithFileName VARCHAR(20) NULL

DECLARE CSVFileName VARCHAR(20)
-- Bulk insert from CSV file
Bulk insert dbo.[MyTable]
from 'C:\file01.CSV' with ( 
    fieldterminator =';'
    ,rowterminator='\n'
    ,FIRSTROW=2
    ,CODEPAGE ='ACP')

-- Insert to new column file name
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET ColumnNameWithFileName = CSVFileName
WHERE ColumnNameWithFileName IS NULL`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql bulk insert with additional column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915209/sql-bulk-insert-with-additional-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable for the file name (and file path if you want) and bulk insert into a #temp table, then INSERT INTO final table with an additional column that will have the file path.

```
declare @filename varchar(255)
set @filename = file.csv
CREATE TABLE #Temp
BULK INSERT #Temp 
from 'C:\file01.CSV' with ( 
    fieldterminator =';'
    ,rowterminator='\n'
    ,FIRSTROW=2
    ,CODEPAGE ='ACP')
insert into [REALFINALTABLE] 
select #temp.*, @filename as [FileName] from #Temp
--Drop #Temp (In case is not necesary any more)
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more elegant way to do it, but you could just do this;

1. import your data from the file into a temporary table
2. select *,FileName into YourTable
3. truncate your temp table
4. process next file

Comment: What do you mean by truncate your temp table?

Comment: In SQL server you use the truncate keyword which removes all records from the table. your DB engine will have similar functionality. Its a good idea to include what your database engine is when you are adding tags to your question. that way we can provide you with more relevant answers, and possibly some code.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 - is that what you mean?

Comment: Yip, That kind of information is what I mean, it all helps.